# Firebase code does not get executed on real iPhone device, only on emulators

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the normal authentication code on my app, the code works fine on emulator. Once tested on device, it does not even start. Below is the snippets for Facebook login, same goes for Twitter or email/pass login.

```
if let fbLoginResult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result {
            if (fbLoginResult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")){
                print("Facebook Token received!")
                FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrent(fbLoginResult.token)
                let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString!
                let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: token)

                print("Token : \(token)")

                FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { (currentUser, linkingError) in
                    if linkingError != nil {
                        print("Linking error: \(linkingError?.localizedDescription)")
                        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                            if error == nil {
                                self.loginSucceeded(user: user!)
                            }else{
                                print("Error : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        })


                    }else{
                        self.loginSucceeded(user: currentUser!)
                    }
                })

            }
        }
```

I have tried switching the Bitcode on Build settings to `NO`. Still unable to work.

How to go about this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by "does not even start", which piece here doesn't start? Have you set up a debugger to determine which line of code is not getting executed? Just by looking at the snippet you've provided, my *guess* is:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { (currentUser, linkingError) in
```

This line will likely fail on a device that hasn't previously authenticated, since `currentUser` would be `nil`, I believe. I would make sure that this variable is non-nil as this is what is likely causing this issue.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That line is not executed. How to go about fixing this ? On a few devices does not really work, only on emulators. Sorry still new with xcode . Thanks @BHendricks

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account should help you -- you need to create an account for a `Firebase` user before you can authenticate them.

Comment: Im abit lost, been browsing through the docs for awhile, the problem is, i tried to link the account of the user when they are signing in, the docs said that i should not sign in but link first, however the current user might be nil. Could you elaborate more ? 
Thanks.

Comment: It's in the docs...if you have a user already authenticated to your Firebase app on a different device, and you don't need to create, then you need to use the `signIn` method, where parameters are the credentials to authenticate, and the `currentUser` is not used. The docs I linked have a sample method implementation of this exact method.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it after thoroughly re reading the docs. You were right. Current user was nil when user never signed in before.